# ERROR Missing number at position 0 when using setValue angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, primeng, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using [Angular 4](https://angular.io/) with reactiveforms, [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/), and [primeng calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) I'm tying to use `setValue` and have tried `patchValue` on a reactiveForm field which contains a Date. This date has been created via a primeng calendar.

`purchaseDate: Sat Sep 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`

I use this 'date' to do a couple of things and then onSumbit of the form I convert the date using `momentjs` to a clean format ready for the backend to accept (i.e. YYYY.MM.DD) using`.moment().format(....`

However when I run the `.setValue` I'm getting the following console error `ERROR Missing number at position 0` and can't figure out why.

```
// convert the date
let newDate = moment(this.form.get('purchaseDate').value).format('YYYY.MM.DD');
// let newDate = moment(this.form.get('purchaseDate')).format('YYYY.MM.DD');
// with or without .value - display the same below (2017.09.01)
console.log(newDate); // 2017.09.01
this.form.get('purchaseDate').setValue(newDate);

// if I create a seperate (empty) reactiveForms field to test against
this.form.get('testField').setValue(newDate) // this works fine
```

I have traced the issue down to when i try to set / patch the primeng calendar value - for some reason is doesn't like to be changed.

**UPDATED** monent format

The issue seams to be happening on the setValue now getting the following error 
`Unexpected literal at position 2 at viewWrappedDebugError`

Comment: You will need to pass in the formGroup value and I don't think moment will accept a single **y**. `moment(this.form.get('purchaseDate').value).format('yy.MM.dd');`

Comment: Moment [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) does not accept lowercase `y` as year token, use `Y`, `YY` or `YYYY` instead. Moreover note that lowercase `dd` token stands for _day of the week_ (`Su` `Mo` ... `Fr` `Sa`), use uppercase `DD` if you want _day of the month_ (`01` `02` ... `30` `31`)

Comment: @JayChase & @VincenzoC hi, thanks - I've updated the code with your suggestion but now getting `ERROR Error: Unexpected literal at position 2`

Comment: FYI @JayChase omitting `.value` makes no difference, I'm logging `newDate` out and the same appears with or without `.value`

Comment: Did you tried to make `newDate` a moment object (`let newDate = moment(this.form.get('purchaseDate').value)`) and then set the value of `purchaseDate` as Javascript Date (using moment [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) : `this.form.get('purchaseDate').setValue(newDate.toDate());`)?

Comment: @VincenzoC Thanks but that just sets the same value as before which is an object `Sat Sep 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) {}` - I want to set a string `2017-09-02` . Hence why I use `.format()`

Comment: There are couple of notes that you should pay attention to regarding Date type and parsing it. First of all, it depends on how you set the type for `purchaseDate` in the backend model and also in the frontend model. If it is set `type: Date`, it won't be able to take in a `string` value. 
Again, it depends on what you are going to do with the `purchaseDate`  that it requires you to set its type to `Date` (Date functions, custom filtering...). If it is not the case, just set its type to `String` then parse your input from the frontend as you want to.
To display, remember there's Pipe.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The thing is that PrimeNG date picker expects to receive instance of `Date` class as a value and it returns instance of a `Date` class as value. So that's why your attempts to put object of other types in there failed.

It's not clear why you attempt to call `setValue()` in the submit handler.

If your goal is to modify value programmatically follow suggestion from VincenzoC in comments - modify object and transform it back to `Date` object before passing it to `setValue()`.

```
let newDate: Date = moment(this.form.get('purchaseDate').value).add(5, 'days').toDate();
this.form.get('purchaseDate').setValue(newDate);
```

If your goal is to format `Date` object for submitting to backend, you don't need to call `setValue()` at all. Format `Date` object to string and pass this string instead of `Date` object to the backend API. If you submitting whole `value` object from form you can modify it this way before submitting:

```
let newDate: string = moment(this.form.get('purchaseDate').value).format('YYYY.MM.DD');
let dataForBackend = { ...this.form.value, purchaseDate: newDate };
this.myBackend.sendData(dataForBackend);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I noticed I tried to give PrimeNG date in a wrong order:

```
{date: "2018-01-31"} - works perfectly fine,
{date: "31-01-2018"} - ERROR Missing number at position 0
```

Was as easy as that in my case.